# Error installing nodejs in arch linux

Tags: linux, node.js

Okay so i just made a fresh install of nodejs package on archlinux using pacman. Command for the same was
`sudo pacman -S nodejs npm` . Now when i tried to run the same i am getting error as

`node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.57:` Which pretty much means that libicu is either not there or not the correct version. The problem that i am facing is that it is not there in pacman. I tried
`sudo pacman -S libicu`, which returned not able to find the package. What is the right way to resolve this issue. FYI : just a note, i would prefer not to install from source and prefer using pacman for the same. If there is any other output that you need to know please comment below and will let you know about the same.

I am currently on manjaro i3 fresh install.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just found out, The name for package in arch linux is `icu` and not `libicu`. Once that is installed node will start working fine.

### Update

After using node for quite sometime i realised that a better way to install node is using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). It would install both node and npm locally and you get the option to manage multiple version.Installation is as simple as

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: Dude, you've just saved me!

Comment: @ademarizu glad i could be helpfull. Although from my long time using node, you might want to consider using nvm(node version manager)  :)

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by installing node js and npm package modules with missing packages that are unsupported by your system how about you try this:

```
$ sudo pacman -Rsc -n nodejs
$ sudo pacman -Sy nodejs
$ sudo pacman -Sy npm
```

Answer (score 1):

did you use testing repo?
If you enabled testing repositories, but later on decided to disable them, you should:

1. Remove/Comment them from /etc/pacman.conf
2. `pacman -Syuu` to "rollback" your updates from these repositories.

*The second item is optional, but keep it in mind if you notice any problems.*

Also you can install stable ver : `pacman -S core/icu`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update arch
sudo pacman -Syu